# Continuously loop through CSS style in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to continuously loop through an array of background URLs, with a delay, to create a 'screensaver' for a website's background.

Currently, I have the array in my .ts file, and am using the NgFor directive in my HTML. The issues are that there is no delay between the switch in images (so the one that ends up being displayed is the last one), and that it is not a continuous loop through the array.

In .ts:

```
  bgImgs = [
`url("/assets/img/friendship.jpeg")`,
`url("/assets/img/family.jpeg")`,
`url("/assets/img/health.jpeg")`,
`url("/assets/img/fatherson2.jpeg")`
```

]

In .html:

```
<div *ngFor="let bgImg of bgImgs">
  <div [style.backgroundImage]="bgImg" id="home" class="pt-5">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a more "rxjs" way of doing this, but here's one way:

```
export class App implements OnInit {
  private imageUrls: string[];
  private current: number = 0;
  currentImage: string;
  constructor() {
    this.imageUrls = [
      '//placehold.it/1280x720.jpg',
      '//placehold.it/1280x721.jpg',
      '//placehold.it/1280x722.jpg',
      '//placehold.it/1280x723.jpg'
    ];
    this.currentImage = this.imageUrls[0]
  }
  ngOnInit() {

    // Every second...
    Observable.interval(1000)
    .subscribe(x => {
      this.currentImage = `url(${this.imageUrls[this.current]})`;

      // Reset current to 0 if we're at the end of the array
      this.current == this.imageUrls.length - 1 ? (this.current = 0) : ++this.current;
    })
  }
}
```

If you want to get into fading or other transitions a bit more legwork is needed.

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/LeZKn5UIL8Nxq0eF5crV?p=preview)